# sparql insert with where clause

Tags: curl, sparql, 4store

How to insert insert query with "where" condition in 4store sparql
As far as I have searched I got to know that we have to use curl command for the same.I tried using this

```
         Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{"bash","-c","curl -i -d 'update=INSERT+DATA+{+?subject2+<http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl/sameAs>+?subject3+.+}+WHERE+{+?subject2+<http://localhost:2020/vocab/Schema_feature>+\""+first[0]+"\"+.+?subject3+<http://localhost:2020/vocab/Schema_feature>+\""+first[1]+"\"+.+}' http://localhost:8000/update/"});
```

but it is saying "WHERE" should not be there.What I am doing wrong?
Is there any other way to do that
With simple insert command I am not able to work in sparql

It is working but for ?subject3 it is entering empty value.I don't know why.When I check the triples for where condition they are showing values

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't

```
insert data { ... } where { ... }
```

You can either insert constant data with:

```
insert data { ... }
```

or you can compute the data to insert with

```
insert { ... } where { ... }
```

It looks like that latter one is what you want here.

Comment: It is working but  for ?subject3 it is entering empty value.I don't know why

Comment: @henrymathew WIthout seeing the query you're actually executing, and without seeing your data, we can't really know either.  What do you mean by "empty value"?

Comment: I have checked with select statement for where clause it is working fine infact when I run a construct it is showing results

Comment: @henrymathew So everything works now?

Comment: no.I am saying that "the where returns the results" but triples matching the first clause are inserted only hence blank node for predicate

Comment: if you write something like `insert { ?x :p ?y } where { ?x :a :b . ?y :c :d }`, you won't insert *anything* unless both `?x :a :b` and `?y :c :d` matched.  Without seeing the actual queries your running and the data in your triplestore, we can't really help any more than that.